# SharePoint Online: Content type property not displayed in details pane and content type not changeable

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, modern-experience, sitepages

I have a site pages library with standard and custom content types. A user has created some pages with the standard "site pages" content type, but should use a customized "content page" content type.

I thought I could easily change the content type via the page property pane as follows:

[image: Screenshot showing the page property pane with content type dropdown]

Unfortunately the "content type property does not show on this sites site pages library. Only name and title are shown:

[image: Screenshot showing the page property pane without content type dropdown]

I am owner of the site. Any hints how to get the content type drop down to show in this library?

Comment: Is this a team site or communication site? How did you create this site, Manually/Programmatically/Migration?

Comment: It’s a communication site and it was added programmatically via a third party SharePoint online management tool.